# jakarta.servlet dependencies mismatch while upgrading spring version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, jetty

dependencies mismatch while upgrading spring version.

I am upgrading my service with spring boot 3.1.4.

This is my `build.gradle`.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id "com.diffplug.eclipse.apt" version "3.38.0"
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.3'
}

group = 'com.app.company'
version = '1.1.0'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket'
        //exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        testImplementation.exclude group: 'org.projectlombok', module: 'lombok'

        if (project.hasProperty('runTests')) {
            testImplementation.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        }
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'jakarta.servlet') {
                // to support jetty on spring boot 3.1.4
                details.useVersion '6.0.0'
            }
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    
    /* my configurations */

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testImplementation'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    configure(options) {
        options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:deprecation' << '-Xlint:unchecked'
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.10"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        csv.required = false
        html.required = true
        // html.destination file("${rootProject.projectDir}/build/reports/jacoco")
        xml.destination file("${rootProject.projectDir}/build/reports/jacoco/report.xml")

    }
}


eclipse {
    jdt {
        apt {
            // You need to run gradle eclipseJdtApt eclipseJdt eclipseFactorypath
            // and restart vscode for this to take effect.
            genSrcDir = file('build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main')
        }
    }
}
```

Here when I am using details.useVersion '5.0.0' my application is running but my testcase are fail to load with this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletConnection
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:210)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)

    ...
```

Now when I am running details.useVersion '6.0.0' my testcase are running but application is not running,  error I am getting

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.app.company.CompanyApplication.main(CompanyApplication.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.newSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.relinkHandlers(ServletContextHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.<init>(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

I was browising this page https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33661 and for spring 3.1.4 we required 6.0.0. But using this my app run is failing.

what I supose to do or what I am missing here. Is there conditional check required.

Comment: Do not create a new question when you made progress. Instead edit and improve the existing question.